# How to list all of javascript functions beginning with _func

Tags: javascript, webkit, javascriptcore

Is it possible to list / return in an array all javascript functions in my own .js file that begin with the string "_func"?

Done in WebKit's JSCore.

Basically, if my file has a bunch of functions, how do I enumerate those functions?

Comment: Are those functions global functions? They better not be. `:)`

Comment: They can either be global or nested inside other functions... or they can be properties of objects.

Comment: Hmm.  In that case, yes, global, but user-defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can loop through the members of the `window` object and test them:

```
var functions = [];

for( var x in window) {
    if(typeof window[x] === "function" && x.indexOf("_func") === 0) {
        functions.push(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't work in a Webkit environment outside of a browser, because 'window' is defined.

Comment: @David In global code the `this` keyword references the global object, so you can replace `window` with `this`...

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by iterating over the members of the `window` object:

```
for (var name in window) {
    if (name.match(/^_func/) && typeof window[name] == 'function') {
        console.log(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't work in a Webkit environment outside of a browser, because 'window' is defined.